# How to perform a repeated Measures with each Subject Receiving each Treatment

Tags: r, anova

The data used is: [https://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/dancer_warmup.dat](https://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/dancer_warmup.dat)

Description: Comparison of 4 Stretching protocols (1=Static Stretching,
2=Dynamic Stretching, 3=Combination Stretching, 4=No Stretch) among
10 dancers (blocks) on vertical jump height.
Data simulated to match paper results.

Variables/Columns
Stretch Protocol    8
Dancer        15-16
Vertical Jump Height (cm)   18-24

I am trying to get the anova and test for treatment effects
This is what I've done so far:

```
stretch <- factor(dancer$Stretch)
blocks <- factor(dancer$Blocks)
moddance <- aov(height ~ stretch + blocks)
  Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
moddance <- aov(height ~ stretch*blocks)
   Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I keep getting the error message, but before when I did it I was able to get the following:

summary(moddance)
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
stretch         3    114    37.9
blocks          9   3403   378.1
stretch:blocks 27     42     1.6

However, I don't think that is the right answer either. How am I supposed to go about this problem?